# Install Windows with QEMU

Tags: qemu

I want to understand if it is possible to install Windows from Qemu to a physical HDD.
I was trying to do that by doing something like this:

```
qemu-system-x64 -m1024 -vnc :1 -hda /dev/sda -cdrom .../Windows.iso
```

Installed successfully. But when i tried to boot normally got a blue screen telling me that a hardware change appeared so go away.

I guess the problem is not because of QEMU-CPU emulation or smth, but because of HDD`s UID change which is used inside of Windows registry. Am i right?

So if yes how to workaround this? Maybe i need to prepare Windows before the reboot?
I have successfully installed FreeBSD via QEMU and thought with Windows it will go the same ...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is. You need to either add the physical computer's drivers to the Windows image before rebooting, or your need to run sysprep with the "Generalize" option to make Windows look for the correct drivers upon booting. This is the same problem as when doing a P2V conversion.

Comment: Add the the physical computer`s hardware? How?
The sysprep hint is clear. I`ll try it. Thank you.

Comment: It's early in the morning... meant drivers, not hardware.

Comment: Hm. How to do that? I think HDD is a pretty common thing so drivers should be inside the Windows already. If not - how to add them?..

Comment: You need drivers for the hard drive controller, not the drive itself. This is typically packaged as a "chipset driver" or "storage controller" or similar.

Comment: But isn`t it already there by default? If i just install Windows over KVM i do not install extra drivers - it automatically catches everything. 
So how to do that?.. I know how to install drivers if the device is already in the 'device manager'.

Comment: Newer versions of Windows can inject drivers with the `dism` utility. Considering your questions, it sounds like sysprepping is going to be simpler to use.